# Overlapping Foreign Keys and Cascade On Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

Lets say I have 4 tables, A,B,C,D.

A has a primary key of ID.
B has a primary key of (ID, A.ID) with A.ID being a foreign key with CASCADE ON DELETE.
C has a primary key of (ID, A.ID) with A.ID being a foreign key with CASCADE ON DELETE.
D has a primary key of (ID, A.ID, B.ID, C.ID), with (A.ID, B.ID) and (A.ID, C.ID) being foreign keys.

Is there any way to CASCADE ON DELETE for both of D's foreign keys? Trying to cascade for both foreign keys gives me a "multiple cascade paths" error dues to both foreign keys cascading deletes of A.ID, but I need to delete the row from D should the row B.ID or C.ID be deleted.

EDIT:

Tables DeviceTypes, DeviceInstances, DeviceDataElements, DeviceDataRecords

DeviceTypes has a primary key of ID.

DeviceInstances has a primary key of (ID, DeviceTypes.ID) with DeviceTypes.ID being a foreign key with CASCADE ON DELETE.

DeviceDataElements has a primary key of (ID, DeviceTypes.ID) with DeviceTypes.ID being a foreign key with CASCADE ON DELETE.

D has a primary key of (ID, Devices.ID, DeviceElements.ID, DeviceInstances.ID), with (DeviceTypes.ID, DeviceElements.ID) and (DeviceTypes.ID, DeviceInstances.ID) being foreign keys.

i.e. A DeviceRecord contains a data point for a DeviceDataElement of a specific DeviceInstance.

Comment: sounds messy to me, can you provide some simple data and scenarios to clarify the table structure.

Comment: Instead of cascading deletes, write a stored procedure that drops the referenced rows in a transaction in the correct order. To enforce use of the procedure you can deny DELETE rights to anyone except the stored procedure.

Comment: @Tanner Gave everything some names to give the situation some more context.

Comment: @Andomar I had a feeling something like that is where I was going to end up with this... Annoying that cascade fails when there are multiple paths. :/

Comment: Please post code. *A has a primary key of ID* is not code.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess about subject area, but as for me, DeviceTypes.ID should not be part of primary key in DeviceInstances and DeviceDataElements. This column is not required to unique identify record in DeviceInstances, for example. It is not possible to have DeviceInstance with same DeviceInstanceID but different DeviceTypeID.

Also I don't think that deletes from DeviceTypes should be cascaded. It is not common (and dangerous) operation to delete from DeviceType. If you have to implement it, write stored procedure, and delete from related tables in correct order (DeviceDataRecords, DeviceDataElements, DeviceInstances, DeviceTypes). Another way to implement this is to mark DeviceType as deleted, not delete physically. In this case you'd never lost your data.

In the same way deletes from DeviceDataElements is under question too. I don't think that DataElements will ever change for some Type.

In this design you have to control from application side that DeviceRecord contains only DataElements allowed by Instance's type. It is very common and natural way to handle this situation (to do it on application or business-logic side). From logical point of view, DeviceDataRecords contains fact that some Instance has some DataElement (of some value). It is unnatural to check types in this table. It is not a good idea to delegate these checks to SQL Server. In case if server side is only available option, you can consider triggers for this task, so on INSERT in Records you can check this rule (it is not a good option too).

I can be wrong on subject area of your application so please correct me or add new information.

```
CREATE TABLE DeviceTypes(DeviceTypeID int not null identity primary key);
go

CREATE TABLE DeviceInstances (DeviceInstanceID int not null identity primary key, DeviceTypeID int not null)
ALTER TABLE DeviceInstances ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeviceInstances_DeviceTypes FOREIGN KEY (DeviceTypeID) REFERENCES DeviceTypes(DeviceTypeID) 
go

CREATE TABLE DeviceDataElements (DeviceDataElementID int not null identity primary key, DeviceTypeID int not null)
ALTER TABLE DeviceDataElements ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeviceDataElements_DeviceTypes FOREIGN KEY (DeviceTypeID) REFERENCES DeviceTypes(DeviceTypeID) 
go

CREATE TABLE DeviceDataRecords (RecordID int not null identity primary key, DeviceInstanceID int not null, DeviceDataElementID int not null)
ALTER TABLE DeviceDataRecords ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeviceDataRecords_DeviceInstances FOREIGN KEY (DeviceInstanceID) REFERENCES DeviceInstances(DeviceInstanceID) on delete cascade
ALTER TABLE DeviceDataRecords ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeviceDataRecords_DeviceDataElements FOREIGN KEY (DeviceDataElementID) REFERENCES DeviceDataElements(DeviceDataElementID) on delete cascade
```